# C - Sudoku solver - Help Understanding a function

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out exactly what the fillSudoku function is doing in this Sudoku solver. The isAvailable checks if the number  will be stopped by numbers in the same row, column, and box. The main function executes everything with checks.

Does anyone understand the functionality/process the fillSudoku function is doing?

```
int isAvailable(int puzzle[][9], int row, int col, int num)
{
    int rowStart = (row/3) * 3;
    int colStart = (col/3) * 3;
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<9; ++i)
    {
        if (puzzle[row][i] == num) return 0;
        if (puzzle[i][col] == num) return 0;
        if (puzzle[rowStart + (i%3)][colStart + (i/3)] == num) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int fillSudoku(int puzzle[][9], int row, int col)
{
    int i;
    if(row<9 && col<9)
    {
        if(puzzle[row][col] != 0)
        {
            if((col+1)<9) return fillSudoku(puzzle, row, col+1);
            else if((row+1)<9) return fillSudoku(puzzle, row+1, 0);
            else return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            for(i=0; i<9; ++i)
            {
                if(isAvailable(puzzle, row, col, i+1))
                {
                    puzzle[row][col] = i+1;
                    if((col+1)<9)
                    {
                        if(fillSudoku(puzzle, row, col +1)) return 1;
                        else puzzle[row][col] = 0;
                    }
                    else if((row+1)<9)
                    {
                        if(fillSudoku(puzzle, row+1, 0)) return 1;
                        else puzzle[row][col] = 0;
                    }
                    else return 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int puzzle[9][9]={{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0},
                      {1, 9, 0, 4, 7, 0, 6, 0, 8},
                      {0, 5, 2, 8, 1, 9, 4, 0, 7},
                      {2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 0, 0, 0},
                      {0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0},
                      {0, 0, 0, 7, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9},
                      {9, 0, 7, 3, 6, 4, 1, 8, 0},
                      {5, 0, 6, 0, 8, 1, 0, 7, 4},
                      {0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

    if(fillSudoku(puzzle, 0, 0))
    {
        printf("\n+-----+-----+-----+\n");
        for(i=1; i<10; ++i)
        {
            for(j=1; j<10; ++j) printf("|%d", puzzle[i-1][j-1]);
            printf("|\n");
            if (i%3 == 0) printf("+-----+-----+-----+\n");
        }
    }
    else printf("\n\nNO SOLUTION\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it via paper/pencil or a debugger?

Comment: Its a not so curious case of `backtracking`, I would look to understand how backtracking works and go from there.

Comment: This is a dup - already posted once today, advised to use a debugger and make notes.  Result - repost:(

Comment: In a nutshell, it is recursively calling itself with the first if section detecting if a number is already in place.  The else section is actually plugging in every available number to make sure that it is a legal move.  Honestly, it is confusing as hell, so I don't blame you.  It might help to add a printf to each section so you can trace how it works.

Answer (score 0):

your question:

*Does anyone understand the functionality/process the fillSudoku function is doing?*

the answer is *Yes*, most of us do understand the functionality/process.

Strongly suggest you edit your question to indicate that YOU don't understand and need some explanation.

And don't repost the same question